# An R function for performing searches

Tags: r, dataset

I am slightly new to writing functions in R. 
Here I have a basic function that searches for a pattern and returns the indexes of where the occurence occurs given a list dataset

```
#this functions takes a pattern and prints the indexes for the matches
find_domain <- function(pattern,list) grep(pattern,list,ignore.case=T)
```

Sometimes during the analysis i found that i need to do that for a larger dataset. The idea is to look for occurence of a domain (pattern) in each of the d7_dataset rows(since each row represents a protein sequence and each column is a domain) such that i can then count the number of sequences that contain or have a given domain(pattern in this case) So i wrote this

```
seqs <- c()
for (i in 1:nrow(d7_dataset)){
       pos <- find_domain("CIDRγ13",d7_dataset[i,])
       if (!is.na(pos[1])) 
        seqs <- c(seqs,1)  
     }

total_seqs <- sum(seqs)
total_seqs
```

However this seems like it can be written as a single function so that i can eliminate duplication and simplify it such that it is generic enough to apply to multiple datasets.
Any ideas on how to condence it to a single function?
In a nutshell, Given a pattern or list of patterns  and a dataset(as a dataframe) to search, return the number of sequences(rows in the dataset) that contain the given pattern.

More or less like this

```
results <– search(a list of patterns to search,dataset)
```

results should look like

```
pattern  count
 pat1     40
 pat2      3
 pat3      0
 .         . 
 .         .
```

It would be very good if the pattern argument would accept a list to search

Thank you

Comment: Just a programming note: it is useless (and will slow down your script) to create a function that just calls another function. There is no real advantage in calling `find_domain` if the only thing it does it's calling `grep`. You are just adding the overhead of another function call.

Comment: you are right! this was a dirty approach and just sounded sort of wrong design though it worked. Am glad that i asked!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your dataset is a matrix, then `grep` will work directly:

```
> set.seed(1)
> bb=matrix(letters[sample(1:20, 100, rep=TRUE)], nrow=20)
> grep("b", bb)
 [1] 10 55 56 69 92
> bb[grep("b", bb)]
[1] "b" "b" "b" "b" "b"
```

If you have multiple patterns, then use `ldply` from package [plyr](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/plyr/index.html):

```
> ldply(c("a", "b", "z"), function(l) data.frame(pattern = l, count = length(grep(l, bb))))
    pattern count
  1       a     2
  2       b     5
  3       z     0
```

Your function `search` then can look like this

```
 search <- function(patlist,data) {
      if(!is.matrix(data)) data <- as.matrix(data)
      ldply(patlist, function(l) data.frame(pattern = l, count = length(grep(l, bb))))
 }
```

Note that this will not work for `data.frame`. So if that is possible you will need to convert it to the matrix, as I did in the code above.

Comment: @mpitkas (+1) Nice one!

Comment: @mpitkas Ah, and yours is faster (by 0.004, on my fake data set). This the way to go...

Comment: And sorry to have mispelled your name (two times) :(

Comment: @chl, no worries, my surname is constantly misspelled by my native language speakers, so my expectations for not misspelling the nickname are really low :)

Answer (score 4):

You should first replace your for loop with something like `apply(d7_dataset, 1, foo)`, where `foo()` is either your function or something along those lines, e.g. `gregexpr()`. The result of `gregexpr()` is a list of numeric vectors with attributes similar to `regexpr()` but giving all matches in each element.

On a related point, there was another function that was proposed as a more user-friendly alternative to `gregexpr()`: [easyGregexpr](http://www.r-bloggers.com/developing-a-user-friendly-regular-expression-function-easygregexpr/).

The following example gives you the number of matches for each row when considering a list of three motifs (in a 10x100 matrix):

```
dd <- replicate(100, replicate(10, paste(sample(letters[1:4], 2),    
                                         collapse="")))
pat <- list("aa", "ab", "cd")
foo <- function(d, p) apply(d, 1, function(x) length(grep(p, x)))
lapply(pat, function(x) foo(dd, x))
```

Comment: for this purpose you can see the stringr package of H. Wickam

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the rstring library!! Awesome approaches! Thanks!